# Simple calculator with binary conversion

Tags: java, netbeans-7.3

There are 2 problems:

1. When I call getText() how canI let the comp know whether the input value is a binary number or a normal number? (my first for loop)
2. The binary converter isnt working as planned

Code extract:

```
    long a,b;
    int c=0,d=0;
    String sa,sb;
    sa=txt1.getText();
    sb=txt2.getText();
    a=Long.parseLong(txt1.getText());
    b=Long.parseLong(txt2.getText());
    int la,lb,ia,ib;
    double ansa = 0,ansb = 0,mainans = 0;
    la=sa.length();
    lb=sb.length();
    if(a>999&&b>999)        
    {
       for(ia=la;ia>=0;ia--)
       {
           if(sa.charAt(ia)=='1')
           {
               double adda;
               adda=Math.pow(2,ia);
               ansa+=adda;
           }
           else
               ansa+=0;      
       }
       for(ib=lb;ib>=0;ib--)
       {
           if(sb.charAt(ib)=='1')
           {
               double addb;
               addb=Math.pow(2,ia);
               ansb+=addb;
           }
               else
               ansa+=0;      
       }      
    }
    else
    {
        ansa=a;
        ansb=b;    
    }
        if(btn1.isSelected()==true)
        mainans=ansa+ansb;
        else
            if(btn2.isSelected()==true)
            mainans=ansa-ansb;
        else 
            if(btn3.isSelected()==true)
                mainans=ansa*ansb;
            else
                if(btn4.isSelected()==true)
                    mainans=ansa/ansb;

         txt3.setText(""+mainans);

        // TODO add your handling code here:
```

Comment: Question doesn't contain a question.

Answer (score 1):

1) I would put two radio buttons to toggle back and forth between binary and base10. A menu works too. Otherwise have binary numbers be prefixed with 0b? If someone enters "10" there is no possible way to tell if this is supposed to be the number 10 or binary 2.

2) The Integer wrapper class has a static method toBinaryString(int i) used as follows:

```
//returns 1010001111
Integer.toBinaryString(655);
```

3) To Convert to String
Cast the number to a string.

```
//Java automatically converts the expression to a string
String s = 1010001111 + "";

//or use toString() method
Integer myInteger = new Integer(655);
myInteger.toString();
```

Comment: thank you :)
and any method to convert a binary number into a binary number into a string?or could u give me a code to convert to do so?